# qsort on a array of characters leading to Seg Fault

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault

In my following program the qsort function is giving a seg fault, I can not understand where I am exactly going wrong:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int cmpfnc (const void *a, const void *b) {
    return *(char *)a - *(char *)b;
}

int checkPermutation_sort (char *s1, char *s2) {
    int l1 = strlen(s1);
    int l2 = strlen(s2);
    if (l1 != l2) return -1;
    
    qsort(s1, l1, sizeof(char), cmpfnc);
    qsort(s2, l2, sizeof(char), cmpfnc);
    return strcmp(s1, s2);
}
int main () {
    printf("%d\n", checkPermutation_sort("abvasfa", "avbasda"));
    
    return 0;
}
```

From what I tried to debug, it is not an error with the comparison function.
It is somewhere going out of memory while sorting.
But I am not able to understand why and how, attaching a screenshot of the function call stack here:

[Function Call Stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1Xb2.png)

The following is debugger output:

```
Reading symbols from a.out...
(gdb) info break

Num     Type           Disp Enb Address            What

1       breakpoint     keep y   0x000000000000121a in checkPermutation_sort 
                                                   at main.c:17
2       breakpoint     keep y   0x000000000000120b in checkPermutation_sort 
                                                   at main.c:15
3       breakpoint     keep y   0x00000000000011b9 in cmpfnc at main.c:7
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/a.out 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, checkPermutation_sort (s1=0x55555555600c "abvasda", s2=0x555555556004 "avbasfa") at main.c:17
17          qsort(s1, l1, sizeof(char), cmpfnc);
(gdb) next

Breakpoint 3, cmpfnc (a=0x55555555600d, b=0x55555555600e) at main.c:7
7           char c = *(char *)a;
(gdb) next
8           char d = *(char *)b;
(gdb) next
9           return c - d;
(gdb) next
10      }
(gdb) next
msort_with_tmp (p=p@entry=0x7fffffffeb20, b=b@entry=0x55555555600d, n=n@entry=2) at ./stdlib/msort.c:143
143     ./stdlib/msort.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) next
145     in ./stdlib/msort.c
(gdb) next
139     in ./stdlib/msort.c
(gdb) next
157     in ./stdlib/msort.c
(gdb) next
159     in ./stdlib/msort.c
(gdb) next
0x00007ffff7db0620 in *ABS*+0xa9c90@plt () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) next
Single stepping until exit from function *ABS*+0xa9c90@plt,
which has no line number information.
__memmove_evex_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:307
307     ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

Comment: Please provide a demonstration of the problem, i.e. something that can be run. I have no issues with [my test](https://godbolt.org/z/qosz5Toqr).

Comment: If it is not the sorting itself, then please provide the bigger context, ideally a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows the problem.

Comment: Thanks, for the input, I thought the main function isn't much useful. But now I understand, it was the culprit, updated the code.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to enable a good set of warnings.  For GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra` as a minimum; consider also `-Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` for identifying some other common mistakes.  For this particular issue, ensure your compiler treats string literals as `char const*` rather than `char*` - that will catch this sort of thing with very little effort.

Answer (score 7):

You are probably passing `"abvasda"` and `"avbasfa"` as string literals to `checkPermutation_sort`, and since they are placed on read only segments and `qsort` is modifying them, you get a segfault.

Switch to

```
char str1[] = "abvasda";
char str2[] = "avbasfa";

checkPermutation_sort(str1, str2);
```

Comment: This is absolutely a *plausible* explanation, but I don't see anything in the question from which I can conclude that it's the *correct* explanation.

Comment: I am actually passing them as string literals. Passing them as variables solved the problem, but a beginner question, how does it make a difference if it is a string literal or a var? Is it like they get different kind of memory allocation or something? Either way it is a pass by value right?

Comment: @AliasgarMusani the main difference is that string literals are placed in the .rodata section (ro stands for read only), take a look to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment